# Receiving an image via jQuery AJAX and displaying the image without the server base64 encoding the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I request an image (`image/jpeg` or `image/png`) from my http sever via an jQuery AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
     'url': '/my/cool/api/server',
     'contentType': 'application/json',
     'data': '{"some":1,"cool":2,"request":3,"data":4}',
     'type': 'POST'
}).done(function(data) {
    // what to do here?
});
```

The server does return the correct image. I want to display the returned image in an `img` tag using the `src=data:image/png;base64,...` syntax. I don't want the server to wrap the image in base64 so I need to do it in the webbrowser via Javascript. How do I do this? The `data` variable in the callback seems to be mangled somehow. Can I get jQuery to return the raw image bytes for me? Or make jQuery encode the data in base64 for me?

I already got a working vanilla JS version, thus I know in principle nit is possible. I am searching for a working jQuery variant of this working vanilla JS code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/my/cool/api/server', true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    var arr = new Uint8Array(this.response);
    var raw = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, arr);
    var b64 = window.btoa(raw);
    var imgElem = document.getElementById('TODOImg');
    imgElem.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + b64;
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: how about getting the server to return the _URL_ to the image, and then just set that as the `src` property of the `img` tag. The browser will then automatically request the new image and display it.

Comment: There is not URL for this image. This question is not about changing the server. Its about changing the client.

Comment: ok fair enough. I just thought it was worth suggesting in case it was possible, since it's much simpler.

Comment: to answer your question about how to do it in jquery, you're more or less there. in the "done" function you do exactly what you would do in the "onload" function of the native xhr request. jQuery's ajax doesn't really support binary data though, so you might need to plug a binary transport into it - see http://www.henryalgus.com/reading-binary-files-using-jquery-ajax/

Comment: @ADyson make this an answer and ill accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do what you've already done, but using jQuery, you're more or less there.

In jQuery's "done" function you do exactly what you would do in the "onload" function of the native XHR request.

However, jQuery's ajax doesn't really support binary data, so you might need to plug a binary transport into it - see http://www.henryalgus.com/reading-binary-files-using-jquery-ajax .